# Computing $\displaystyle\int_S x^2ydxdydz$ given a particular change of variables.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Let $S=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x>0, y\ge 1,z\ge 1, xyz\le 1\}.$ Find the set $S^*$ obtained by the change of variables : $$\begin{cases}x=u\\ y=\frac{u+v}u\\z=\frac{u+v+w}{u+v}.\end{cases}$$
> and compute $\displaystyle\int_S x^2ydxdydz.$

**My attempt:**

The condition $xyz\le 1,x>0$ gives $$xyz=u\cdot\frac{u+v}u\cdot\frac{u+v+w}{u+v}=u+v+w=1$$

On the other hand $x>0, y,z\ge 1, xyz\le 1\implies 0<x\le 1.$

Also, $y=\frac{u+v}u=1+\frac{v}u\ge 1, u>0\implies v\ge 0.$

Then, $\begin{aligned}z&=\frac{u+v+w}{u+v}\\&=1+\frac{w}{u+v}\ge 1, u+v>0\implies w\ge 0.\end{aligned}$

Altogether, $$\begin{cases}u+v+w\le 1, 0<u\le 1\\ 0\le v\\ 0\le w\end{cases}\\\implies v,w\le 1.$$

We can express $u,v,w$ in terms of $x,y,z:$
$$\begin{cases}u=x\\v=xy-x\\z=xyz-xy\end{cases}$$
The Jacobian determinant is then $J_\psi(u,v,z)=\frac1{J_{\psi^{-1}}(x,y,z)}=\frac1{x^2y}=\frac1{f(x,y,z)}$

I set the integral like this $$\begin{aligned}\int_Sx^2ydxdydz&=\int_{\psi(S^*)}x^2ydxdydz\\&=\int_0^1\int_1^\infty\int_1^{1/xy}x^2ydxdydz\\&=\int_0^1\int_0^{1-u}\int_0^{1-u-v}dxdydz\\&=\frac13\frac{1\cdot 2}2\cdot 1\\&=\text{volume of a tetrahedron }\\&=\frac16\end{aligned}$$

One problem I have is that the determinant $\frac1{x^2y}$ isn't bounded as it is supposed to be if we want to apply the following theorem:

> Let $C\subseteq\Bbb R^2$ be an open bounded set (which has an area, meaning $\chi_C$ is integrable over any rectangle $B\supseteq C$). Let $\varphi:C\to\Bbb R^2$ be an injection of class $C^1$. Suppose the Jacobian determinant $J_\varphi(x)=\det\nabla\varphi(x)$ is nonzero, $\forall x\in C$ and that $|J_\varphi(x)|$ and $\frac1{|J_\varphi(x)|}$ are bounded functions on $C$. Suppose $D=\varphi(C)$ has an area. If $f:D\to\Bbb R$ is Riemann integrable, then $(f\circ\varphi)|J_\varphi|$ is integrable on $C$ and $$\int_Df=\int_C(f\circ\varphi)|J_\varphi|.$$

**Question 1:** Should I justify my computations with the following lemma:

> Let $C\subseteq\Bbb R^2$ be a bounded set which has an area/Jordan measure and $g:C\to\Bbb R$  a bounded function. Suppose $(C_\delta)_{\delta>0}\subset C$ is a collection of sets that have an area with $\lim_{\delta\to 0}\nu(C_\delta)=0$ s. t. $g_{\mid C\setminus C_\delta}$ is integrable on $C\setminus C_\delta,\forall \delta>0$. Then $g$ is integrable on $C$ and $$\lim_{\delta\to 0}\int_{C\setminus C_\delta}g=\int_Cg.$$

**Question 2:** Have I done any mistake so far?

**Question 3:** Is there any reason (other than terms canceling) for this particular change of variables? I don't think I would've ever come up with that idea.